# Using img2txt in Midnight Commander

Tags: terminal, python, images, homebrew, midnight-commander

As far as I know it is possible to use img2txt with Midnight Commander as described [here](https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/2977). My question is how to setup (in details) img2txt on Mac and how to use it with MC.

OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.2

MC: 4.8.20 (installed with Homebrew)